# String.substring(index) has stopped my thread in debug mode

Tags: java, string, eclipse, j2mepolish, java-wireless-toolkit

I work with j2me polish 2.0.7, in eclipse 3.4.2, with wtk2.5.2_01. 
I create control which draws text: normal, bold, and italic.

The code below is parsing raw text, and search for * and _ symbols, if found than add to draw vector the text and the drawer, and it's just stops after getting second time to the line 58:
`String test = new String(raw_text_buff.substring(iter));`
it stops in raw_text_buff.substring(iter), ONLY in debug mode..

raw text is: `bla bla bla *1000* bla bla`

Full code:

```
private String raw_text = "bla bla bla *1000* bla bla";
Vector draw_items = null;

private void prepareText()
{
    char open_char = 0; 
    int open_pos = 0;
    Object []param = null;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String raw_text_buff = new String(raw_text);
    int iter = 0;
    boolean was_reset = false; 
    while(true)
    {
        char c = raw_text_buff.charAt(iter);



        if(iter == raw_text_buff.length() || c == '*' || c == '_')
        {
            if(sb.length() > 0) 
            {
                BmFont viewer = null;
                String str = sb.toString();

                if(open_char == '*' && null != bm_strong)
                {
                    viewer = bm_strong.getViewer(str);
                }else
                if(open_char == '_' && null != bm_italic)
                {
                    viewer = bm_italic.getViewer(str);
                }else if(null != bm_normal)
                {
                    viewer = bm_normal.getViewer(str);
                }else
                {

                }

                param = new Object[2];

                param[0] = str;
                param[1] = viewer;

                if(null == draw_items)
                    draw_items = new Vector();

                draw_items.addElement(param);

                sb = new StringBuffer();

                if(open_char == 0 && (c == '*' || c=='_'))
                    open_char = c; 
                else
                    open_char = 0; 

                String test = new String(raw_text_buff.substring(iter)); // stucks here.
                raw_text_buff = test;
                iter = 0;
                was_reset = true;
            }else
            {
                open_char = c;
            }


            if(iter == raw_text_buff.length())
                break;
        }else
        {
            sb.append(c);

        }

        ++iter;
    }


}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Off-topic comment: never do `new String( something )` when `something` is already a String.

Comment: Alexander, thanks for your comment, can you please explain your opinion?

I do this because, in debugger i saw that, after first calling:
`raw_text_buff = raw_text_buff.substring(iter)`
raw_text_buff was not a new string instance, it was old string instance with field "offset"(with value of iter).. and i thought that problem is in it.

Comment: Since Strings are immutable, this is the fast way to create substrings :).

Comment: Not in this case (here the copy is unneccessary), but sometimes it **is** a good idea to crate a new String. That's because of a common optimization where String.substring() re-uses the original underlying char array. This means that if you create a 1-character substring from a string of 1 million characters, the substring will still be taking the same space as the million-character one. By creating a `new String(str.substring(...))`, you force the 1 char to be copied and the 1 million can be freed if no longer needed. But it's a very special kind of situation of course.